# EMI filter for 3v3 over cat5

Tags: filter, protection

I am running a differential pair over cat5 along with 3v3 and Gnd. I have tested the circuit with a 10m cat5 cable and noticed very little ripple looking at the 3v3 supply on a scope. I am unsure about protection for this circuit though. Currently I have a 1uF and 0.1uF filter cap on the 3v3 supply on each end. Is this sufficient? Should I add any other components such as protection diodes, bigger caps or an inductor?

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's a bad idea to run your regulated voltage through a cable - there's the voltage drop due to the cable. Nevertheless, in certain circumstances you can do this.

At a minimum, I'd suggest a transzorb across the 3V3/0V pair at both ends. As well, a polyfuse at the supply side in series with the 3V3 to limit the short circuit current. Some more bulk capacitance at the load end wouldn't hurt - 47uF or 100uF. Note - the assumption that only fairly small currents are expected - in the order of 100mA.

To get a handle on the expected voltage drop, the nominal resistance of CAT5 is around 12.5 Ohm/100m. At 10m this would be 1.25 Ohm each way (3V3 and 0V wires), so 2.5 Ohms.
Apply Ohm's law: V= IR = 0.1 * 2.5 = 0.25V drop. That's nearly 10%. Depending on your load this could be getting marginal. You could use two or three pairs in parallel to lower this. This should illustrate why sending regulated power over a cable is generally a bad idea.

For example: PoE uses 48V then regulates this at the point of load. Switching regulators are used for power conversion. For your 3.3V at 100mA (my spec) ends up being around 10mA at 48V so the resistive loss is much less: 0.025V drop over 48V is around 0.05%.

A 'simple' solution is to run, say 12V then have a regulator at the load end. Ensure there is a fuse or some other means to limit the current through the wire - failure to do this could create a fire hazard. Then there's the issue of lightning and other transients - tranzorbs are one solution - on both ends of the cable.

An 'off the shelf' solution to your problem would be to use PoE (PoE switches are fairly inexpensive these days or there's PoE injectors) and a PoE 'splitter' or device module which converts PoE back down to a lower voltage. This would work even if you're not using Ethernet - you'd need to choose your pairs carefully though.

I've digressed a bit from your question, but what you ask is a fairly common problem and many learn the hard way that it is not quite as simple as they'd like, thus the suggestion of using PoE.

Comment: Its sad that they didn't adopt the original spec, as 120Vac current limited to 100W and ground isolated would have been better than what we ended up with. That is why I hear at times cat6 cable heating up and running hot for some people in their installations. But maybe this will change in the future, as it took them over 25 years for them to establish GCFI/AFI circuit practices.

Comment: @DavidMikeska. 120VAC for PoE sounds dangerous. I don't think your comment is relevant to the OP's issue though.

Comment: That was the original standards when they invented the cable. @Kartman and 120VAC is not really a big deal when it is handled correctly. 50VDC is actually more dangerous because of the current, and even a fire hazard because the wire was not designed for those currents. But since the OP needs just low voltage, a 24vac transformer could deliver as much power they need to their accessory

Comment: The other advantage to running AC is that the acessory can rectify and regulate and clean up the power efficiently no matter how much noise get induced. @Kartman That is why it was conceived that way.

Comment: High current AC in the same cable as low current AC - induction? That might be a problem

Comment: 833mA @120V  will not heat up the 24Ga wire compared to 50V @ 2A

Comment: I wasn't referring to heating - CMRR might be an issue on the signal wires.

Comment: All signal wires are balanced connections , so it initially those circuits have 40db of common mode signal rejection to begin with. Btw, the frequency bandwidth ratings were done with 120V on a pair while doing the test for bleed characteristics. there is no skin effect on low frequency ac

Comment: The twist on the brown pair is for 50 to 400 hz AC Others are twisted for rating of speed.@kartman

Comment: thanks for this. I was thinking a redesign for 5v would be required, although voltage drop was acceptable for the requirements. I'll figure out a suitable TVS and add 47uF on the supply. Seems my current (pun) polyfuse was underspecified so that aswell will require a look (new multimeter in the mail). Also nice that a conversation is allowed with forum nazis not needing to bot format everything lol

Comment: the TVS I went with is 
https://lcsc.com/product-detail/TVS_MDD-Microdiode-Electronics-SD03_C502526.html
I think it looks ok...

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you now, DC isn't really engineered to go through CAT5 or CAT6 cable, but due to some agency somewhere, we have to deal with dc on POE cat6 and of course, this has caused small issues installers have to deal with. The cross talk that will happen, its going to happen. However, the best method for DC is for the blue pair (both wires) be +DC voltage and the brown pair (both wires) be DC ground. If you can change your system to AC voltage with some low voltage transformer, you will be able to distribute this long run more efficiently and noise wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: IEEE 802 Family? aah cool using i2c over differential pair, so assuming will be ok (not shooting for LAN specifications for cable length)

Comment: The only application in the field I seen i2c differential on cat5 was done in the professional audio sector. @Bringle Ever heard of AES50 (AKA copper based MADI)?

Comment: no looks interesting though. Mine is just for sensors